# How can I get the maximum amount of characters for Single Line Text view before it ellipsis?

Tags: android

I have a TextView that is as wide as device's width. I have a String that will go in it that could exceed hundreds of characters.

What I need to display in a single line is characters from index of zero to (numCharsWideInTextView - 8) of that string. The remaining 8 characters will be used to add a custom suffix. Take for example the following:

```
String label = "How can I get the maximum amount of characters for Single Line 
Text view before it ellipsis? (4392)"

String maxChars = 20;
String str = truncate(label, maxChars);
TextView tv = new TextView();

// "How can I get the ma…(#4392)" is what should appear in TextView where #4392 is a sticky suffix
tv.setText(str); 

private String truncate(String str, int maxChars) {
     String issueId = // Some regEx function to be written 
     String s = str.subString(0, maxChars)
     s += "…" + "(#" + issueId + ")"
     return s;
}
```

I am trying not to go down the road of hard coding it or having to write different resource/dimens values. You can see here I hardcoded it as 20. How can I evaluate this programatically at runtime?

There must be a way, a function, that will return the number of characters that will fit in a TextView before it will new line or ellipize. The value should be different if the TextView is being in Portait vs Landscape configuration.

I tried combing through the docs TextView, FontMetrics, Paint, etc. but no luck.

Comment: Probably its not possible to solve it generally, because each character has its own width (if you dont use a special font). There will fit more i´s than w´s in one line. So maybe hardcoding is the better way...

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isTooLarge (TextView text, String newText) {
    float textWidth = text.getPaint().measureText(newText);
    return (textWidth >= text.getMeasuredWidth ());
}

private int ellipsisedAt(TextView text, String newText) {
    for (int i = 0; i < newText.length; i++) {
         if (isTooLarge(text, newText.substring(0, i))) {
              return i;
         }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Why this doesn't work?

**EDIT**

Also you can try to use MONOSPACE typeface and measure only one symbol width and work with it everywhere. Much easier way, much faster code